# Can't run an AppImage on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fuse, appimage

I'm not able to run AppImages on my Ubuntu 20.04. All the permissions are ok (see pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb51z.png)) and I have tried the terminal too (see pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvgCL.png)). The messages in the terminal are `dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2` and `AppImages require FUSE to run.` but fuse is already installed (see pic [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVlVm.png)), it says `fuse is already the newest version (2.9.9-3)`. I've tried to reinstall fuse with the `--reinstall` apt option, same results.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance :)

[image: Permissions are ok]

[image: Tried the terminal]

[image: Fuse is already installed]

Comment: ia32 sounds strange. What do you have for `arch; uname -a`?

Comment: It was the wrong arch indeed. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/troubleshooting/fuse.html

Answer (score 67):

I solved the issue related to the error message:

```bash
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run.
```

By installing FUSE.

For Ubuntu < 22.04 use:

```bash
sudo apt-get install fuse libfuse2
```

For Ubuntu >= 22.04 use:

```bash
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Source: https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/troubleshooting/fuse.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I did required `fuse` for my AppImage to work on Ubuntu >= 22.04.

Comment: Similarly to what Bono said, I (thought I) required `fuse` too on Jammy, having `libfuse2` already installed without Etcher correctly running. It turned out that `apt install fuse` made up a REAL PACKAGE MESS because it said `fuse3 kdeconnect kio-fuse kubuntu-desktop ntfs-3g plasma-discover-backend-snap sshfs xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-kde`. Then be careful.

Answer (score 4):

You have to download appimage for your actual CPU architecture.

The most popular is amd64. So download link for BalenaEtcher would be https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.5.122/balenaEtcher-1.5.122-x64.AppImage .

Comment: Can't believe I've dowloaded the wrong version. Now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: For someone who downloaded the correct version should run `sudo apt-get install fuse libfuse2` and enjoy

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos installing `libfuse2` did the trick for me. Not `fuse`, that would conflict with `fuse3` that I already have, but the library was required

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling to run Etcher as AppImage on Ubuntu, I suggest the [proper way](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher?d_id=18fc8748-449a-4dd2-b9f1-7b099e183eb3&s_id=1705836110195#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64) as the one pointed out from the authors.

Messing up with `fuse` / `libfuse2` caused dependency hell on my Jammy host, so be careful.

```
dpkg: fuse3: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 kio-fuse depends on fuse3.
 encfs depends on fuse; however:
  Package fuse is not installed.
  Package fuse3 which provides fuse is to be removed.
 cryfs depends on fuse; however:
  Package fuse is not installed.
  Package fuse3 which provides fuse is to be removed.
```